# how to make one to many relation with foreign key

Tags: prisma

```
model Categories{
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name String @db.VarChar(30)
  products Products[]
}

model Products{
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  englishName String @db.VarChar(40) @map("english_name")
  category Categories @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId String  
  imgUrl String @map("img_url")
}
```

Hi! I'm connecting model categories and model products as one to many relations. I want to set categoryId in model Products as a foreign key, but it's not working. Someone please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little bit your schema:

```
model Categories{
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name String
  products Products[] @relation()
}

model Products{
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  englishName String
  category    Categories @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId  Int
}
```

After I have run the migration and finally I have executed the following:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const saveData = async () => {
  const category = await prisma.categories
  .create({
    data: {
      name: 'Category 1',
    }
  });

  console.log(category);

  const product = await prisma.products
  .create({
    data: {
      englishName: 'Product 1',
      category: {
        connect: {
          id: category.id
        },
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(product);

  const products = await prisma.products
  .findMany({
    include: {
      category: true
    }
  });

  console.log(products);
};


saveData();
```

and here you go the result

[image]